# Secondary drive has been renamed incrementally

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, disk, disk-usage

I have a small problem, I'm not stuck at all

I have a Kubuntu 20.04 with a secondary disk of 1Tb and a partition called "data"
I'm using this OS since 4 mounth now and I've noticed something strange : sometime my disk has been renamed incrementally

By this I mean that before my partition was called "data", then it become  "data1" and today it's "data2"
It's still the same disk, I didn't loose anything

It's looks like something got locked in my partition, so my computer rename the partition just next to
In these "ghosts partitions" there is only empty folder of my VSCode & Docker projects...

[image]

(Edit)
Here my fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=8a46622d-3dda-4e60-8158-58ab98b190cd /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=70CD-EC24  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=0be1387f-8a6e-46a1-88d1-3b2a53a855b0 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

If somebody have an idea of what happened !
Thanks in advance !

Comment: How is the drive being mounted?

Comment: Well it's just an hard drive pluged in SATA on my computer... So it's mounted when the system start I think...

Comment: Can you add the contents of your /etc/fstab file to the question please.

Comment: Here for you !.

Comment: How do you mount /data ? It isn't in /etc/fstab.

Comment: Ho that's maybe why, I just plugged my disk on my computer with a SATA cable...  
I don't really know what is fstab, should I put some configuration inside to declare my disk ?